# Google Play Games - Games.API is not available on this device

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games, google-play-developer-api, google-auth-library

I use my own game engine for multiple apps. The following code works on some apps with newer Google Play setups. But on an old app I get now an exception when I try to show the leaderboard or achievement intent. But the same app works on the second test device with another Google account. Both devices are Huawei P 30 Pro. It seems that the Google account is the problem.

- App-A works on device A and B
- App-B works on device A but not on device B
- Device A and B are the same model
- Both apps use the same code

```
public void onCreate()
{
    ...

    // Create the client used to sign in to Google services.
    m_googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(ASCore.core.context(),
        new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN).build());
    signInSilently();

    ...
}

private void signInSilently()
{
    if (m_googleSignInClient == null) return;

    ASCore.logD(TAG, "signInSilently()");

    m_googleSignInClient.silentSignIn().addOnCompleteListener(ASCore.core.context(),
           task -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    ASCore.logD(TAG, "signInSilently(): success");
                    onConnected(task.getResult());
                } else {
                    ASCore.logE(TAG, "signInSilently(): failure");
                    onDisconnected();
                }
            });
}

private void onConnected(GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount)
{
    ASCore.logD(TAG, "onConnected(): connected to Google APIs");

    m_achievementsClient = Games.getAchievementsClient(ASCore.core.context(), googleSignInAccount);
    m_leaderboardsClient = Games.getLeaderboardsClient(ASCore.core.context(), googleSignInAccount);

    ...
}
```

The following call works:

```
m_leaderboardsClient.submitScore(id, score);
```

But show an intent throw an exception:

```
m_leaderboardsClient.getLeaderboardIntent(id).addOnSuccessListener(intent -> ASCore.core.context().startActivityForResult(intent, RC_UNUSED))
            .addOnFailureListener(e -> handleException(e, ASCore.core.context().getString(R.string.leaderboards_exception)));

m_achievementsClient.getAchievementsIntent().addOnSuccessListener(intent -> ASCore.core.context().startActivityForResult(intent, RC_UNUSED))
            .addOnFailureListener(e -> handleException(e, ASCore.core.context().getString(R.string.achievements_exception)));
```

Exception:

```
2021-08-25 09:29:31.349 21243-21243/com.asgardsoft.words E/AS AS Bug: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 17: API: Games.API is not available on this device. Connection failed with: ConnectionResult{statusCode=INTERNAL_ERROR, resolution=null, message=null}
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.ApiExceptionUtil.fromStatus(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.5.0:4)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.ApiExceptionMapper.getException(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.5.0:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zah.zaa(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.5.0:18)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager$zaa.zaa(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.5.0:212)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager$zaa.zaa(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.5.0:218)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager$zaa.zaa(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.5.0:340)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager.handleMessage(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.5.0:179)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

Comment: see "Games.API is not available on this device."

Comment: It is available, otherwise we hide the button like on Amazon devices. The same code/apk works on other devices. Also the same code inside another app(other ids) works on this device.

Comment: Some Huawei devices have not Google Play services and have own (by Huawei )